# capturar la pantalla y generar un pdf

Tags: angular, frontend

me encuentro en un problema, en una de las tareas del proyecto en que me encuentro, tengo que capturar la pantalla de uno de los componentes de la aplicacion web, el cual es la ultima pantalla del carrito de compras.
He investigado en youtube y chatgpt, y las opciones son html2canvas, jspdf, pdfMake y print-js, pero ninguna de estas me funciona, cada vez que las instalo las importaciones me dan error,o una de las continuaciones esta mala o deprecada.

```
  downloadPdf(filename: string) {
    try {
      

      const pdf = new jsPDF('landscape', 'pt', 'a4');
    
    html2canvas(document.getElementById('recibo')!, {
      scale: 2,
      allowTaint: true,
      useCORS: true,
    }).then((canvas: any) => {
      const pdfWidth = pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
      const pdfHeight = (canvas.height * pdfWidth) / canvas.width;
  
      pdf.addImage(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'),'PNG', 10, 10, pdfWidth, pdfHeight);
      pdf.save(filename);
    })
      
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error al capturar la pantalla:', error);
    }
    
  }
```

PDFDocument y las demas me dan problemas de importacion, y realmente necesito terminar este ticket, porque mi team lider, le dio una especificacion de sp2, y llevo todo el día, tambien cabe decir que soy junior aún, pero igual

Comment: Pues si tu _team leader_ le ha dado dicha especificción al Ticket, te sugiero que lo discutas con él y que te oriente. Sobre todo si eres Junior, tal como parece.

Comment: como estas haciendo las importaciones?

Comment: Hola a todos, hem mi team leader tambien es junior, me dijo que encontrara solucion nomas

Comment: Estoy haciendo las importaciones_ import { jsPDF } from 'jspdf';
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';
hasta el momento me funciona, me hace captura de pantalla y convierte al pdf, pero no puedo acceder a una de las imagenes, creo que es por la seguridad del firebase

Comment: Firebase suele tener el CORS activado por defecto, si este es el caso deberás modificarel CORS mediante su CLI

Answer (score 1):

Primero hay que asegurar que se tienen las dependencias:

```
npm install jspdf
npm install html2canvas
```

Tambien puedes validar, que esta correctamente instalados:

- Desde la consola de comandos: Abre una consola de comandos en la raíz de tu proyecto y ejecuta los siguientes comandos para verificar la instalación:

```
npm list jspdf
npm list html2canvas
```

- Verificar dependencias en `package.json`: Abre tu archivo `package.json` y asegúrate de que las dependencias estén listadas. Deberías ver algo similar a esto:

```
"dependencies": {
  // Otras dependencias...
  "jspdf": "^1.5.3",
  "html2canvas": "^1.3.2",
  // Otras dependencias...
}
```

- Revisar la carpeta `node_modules`: En el directorio de tu proyecto, busca la carpeta `node_modules`. Deberías ver carpetas llamadas `jspdf` y `html2canvas` dentro de ella. Si no están allí, es posible que la instalación no se haya realizado correctamente.

---

Luego las importaciones se deben realizar asi:

```
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';
```

documentacion: [jsPDF](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf#usage) y [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/getting-started)

El codigo que compartiste luce correcto:

```
downloadPdf(filename: string) {
  try {
    const pdf = new jsPDF('landscape', 'pt', 'a4');

    html2canvas(document.getElementById('recibo')!, {
      scale: 2,
      allowTaint: true,
      useCORS: true,
    }).then((canvas: any) => {
      const pdfWidth = pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
      const pdfHeight = (canvas.height * pdfWidth) / canvas.width;

      pdf.addImage(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'), 'PNG', 10, 10, pdfWidth, pdfHeight);
      pdf.save(filename);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error al capturar la pantalla:', error);
  }
}
```